# html dropdown in jquery mobile

Tags: asp.net, jquery-mobile

I have a html dropdown where the data is binded from database using ajax json .The values are showing according to id and it is binding in dropdown according to selected id. But the problem is after applying jquery mobile css the value is not showing in dropdown. If i dont include the css the val;ue appears in dropdown. What function i need to include for jquery mobile controls.

My code:

```
<link href="../CSS/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/themes/default/my.css" />



<div data-role="fieldcontain" style="width: 50%">
    <label for="selectmenu22">
        <span style="font-family: times new roman,times; font-size: medium;">
        <b>Address Details:</b>
        </span>
    </label>
    <select  name="selectmenu22" id="ddlAddressDetails" required="required"  data-theme="b" data-mini="true" runat="server">
    </select>
</div>
```

```js
var table=document.getElementById("ddlAddressDetails"); 
var selectData="";
var data = $.ajax({

          url: 'ViewSurvey.aspx',                                                            
          data: {ID:function(){return EID}},
          dataType: 'json', 
          async: false, 
          success: function(data, result) 
                    {                                                             
                     if (!result)
                     {
                      alert('Failure to retrieve the data.'); 
                     }
                     else
                     {
                     for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
                     {     

                        selectData+="<option selected='selected' 
value='"+data[i].ID+"'>"+data[i].OriginDestinationAddress+"</option>"              
                     }  
                     table.innerHTML=selectData;  

                 }
}
});

return table;
}
```

Comment: Any sample of code? We need see this CSS. Maybe there is something wrong.

Comment: value is binded but it doesnot display in html dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You need refresh your dropdown to update items that are prepared but aren't been showing. Try using:

```
$('#ddlAddressDetails').selectmenu('refresh');
```

**EDIT**

Try using this code to add items to dropdown:

```
$('#ddlAddressDetails').append($('<option></option>').val(data[i].ID).html(data[i].OriginDestinationAddress));
```

Comment: actually it is binding for me but when i am using jquerymobile css the data is not displaying by default